# External data pack error

Tags: objects

External data pack error
Missing file  blender 2.9
I want Blender to always be able to find the texture (even if the file is on a different computer).

But [all packed in .blend]
It says that the path cannot be found.
Why are you looking for that directory?

-Is there a problem with the directory?
How should I set up the directory?

-This object is exported from ue4.
Having trouble exporting from UE4?

Are there any tutorials that might help

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because Blender caches textures, they won't appear missing right away, showing pink color. To become pink, they should be reloaded. Like when you reopen the .blend file or append/link their texture data blocks to another .blend file.

Before packing, you have to find all missing textures in the original file.

When you use **Find Missing Files**, you have to choose the folder with missing files. Blender will search in the folder's subfolders also. To find files on your computer use something like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

In Blender, there is no such concept as a project or a project folder.
There are no requirements for strict directory management like in Unreal Engine.

You may also want to disable using relative paths so you can move a .blend file freely.

[image]

Some methods of importing, like with some add-ons, may ignore this setting, so you have to make path absolute manually.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the idea of a project folder in blender is using relative paths. Relative to the location of the saved blend file.   Eg `//textures/foo.png` is in the folder "textures" in the same folder as the blend file.  Could use  to emulate the structure required by other software.  This folder could  be symbolically linked to any folder  on your system via the OS. Project can be distributed as a zip, or packed.  Will then unpack relative to the blend file folder.  Using absolute paths is far more likely to break if you use the blend file on another computer where the absolute paths may not exist